Can distance traveled by a body be zero?
I had seen a teacher saying on YouTube that we must note that distance traveled can not be zero then I searched for the same on net and surely some sources say same e.g. the below link
https://byjus.com/question-answer/is-distance-can-be-zero/
Now I want to know is this really correct to say distance can never be zero.

They're saying that if there is movement, then the distance traveled is zero. The point of this is to distinguish between distance and displacement. If you move and come back to your original point, net displacement is zero but net distance traveled is positive.  So while it's silly to say that distance can't be zero (since objects can remain stationary), that's not the point of what they're saying.

Distance traveled refers to the total length of the path taken by an object, regardless of direction.
Scenarios:

If an object remains stationary (doesn't move), the distance traveled is zero.
If an object moves along a certain path and then retraces its exact steps back to its starting point, the total displacement is zero, but the distance traveled is non-zero because it has moved along a path.

Thus, saying "distance traveled can never be zero" is not accurate. It can indeed be zero if there's no movement.
When discussing distance in the context of both space and time, an object can be at rest in the 3 spatial dimensions, but will always be traveling forward in time.
